# Add a tax to your listing on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, listings

I want to create a website for dealership cars and I want to know if this is a way to add a tax when a customer want to publish a listing. I find something on google but they said that is only working on PayPal and somehow it limits the user to only post jobs - not cars or anything else.In my country PayPal is not an option for many people. Do you have any idea what should I do?
The website is made with Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin in order to transform your wordpress website to an e-commerce platform. Most popular one is WooCommerce which has an integrated tax system: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/

Comment: yes but this payment I want to be only for users that becomes sellers on my website. When they post their car , I want to pay an amount for their post to be publicate on the website

Comment: I see, so you are looking for something to create a multi-vendor website.
You can search for dokan or wcfm (they are the 2 most popular plugins for woocommerce) this way you can charge commision's everytime another seller, sells a product he added on your website.